# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Vat' and 'int'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

been searching and i cant find a proper solutions I have issue calculating Vat amount from 2 values in Django models.

first the VAT model is like this

```
class Vat(models.Model):
    vat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    vat_value = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vat_value)
```

then I have the Statement model as below

```
class Statement(models.Model):
    sales_invoice   = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vat_value       = models.ForeignKey(Vat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    amount_in       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

def vat_amt_in(self):
        if self.amount_in and self.vat_value :
            vat_amt_in = (self.vat_value/100)*self.amount_in
        else:
            return None
```

so after this I get the Error

> unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Vat' and 'int'

anyone can help with this for me to get the correct vat amount

like if vat_value = 21 and amount_in =50 then vat_amt_in =10,50

Comment: thank you so much. That's what I wanted. it works, How do I mark this comment as an answer?

Comment: I added it as one - feel free to delete the copied one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from `self.vat_value/100`, where the first argument is type Vat, not something divisible by an integer. You probably wanted `self.vat_value.vat_value/100` (if IntegerField() is divisible by an integer).